# Does a high latex content improve crack resistance in paint?

Tags: walls, painting, foundation, renovation

My wife an I want to paint the walls and ceiling of a small apartment in a faraway country and are, like many, confused in choosing between using acrylic and "latex" (which I seem to understand really is acrylic too) paints.

The building is of bricks and has no foundations, making walls prone to cracking. Everything was cleaned up with gypsum and/or plaster and no crack appear at the moment.

I believe it won't last if the paint to be used isn't resistant to mechanical stress.

We have a choice between quality paint claimed to be acrylic with "some little latex" in it or relatively expensive paint with "a high ratio (90%) of latex".

Which one should be expected to be more flexible? Loads of contradicting infos to my understanding and pros around here haven't been more helpful unfortunately.

It would be really great to hear what you knowledgeable people think!
Thank you

Comment: As a practical matter, if the walls crack, the paint cracks, for any normal class of "paint". So, don't concern yourself with a mythical case of "paint that won't crack when the walls do" unless it's being applied by unicorns.

Comment: Latex paint does not contain any latex at all.  This is a misnomer. And no paint would be 90% of anything; even galvanized roof coating isn't 90% zinc.  The people you are talking to *are not paint chemists* to put it mildly.

Comment: Indeed there's no latex in it and a large crack would crack the paint. The building is rather unsteady by modern 'western' standards but not terrible. Hence I was asking about elasticity in different types of paint. Elasticity, however limited, of the coating material might keep tiny movements within the building shape from showing on the new walls. I've read online that paint announced as being acrylic is more elastic than the one advertised as being latex-based and it conflicts with other things i've hear around here.

Comment: IMHO, what you're asking about isn't really a thing, so I would expect anecdotal accounts to vary.